# Terraform: Error when creating azure kubernetes service with local_account_disabled=true

Tags: terraform, azure-aks

An error occurs when I try to create a AKS with Terraform. The AKS was created but the error still comes at the end, which is ugly.

```
        │ Error: retrieving Access Profile for Cluster: (Managed Cluster Name 
"aks-1" / Resource Group "pengine-aks-rg"): 
    containerservice.ManagedClustersClient#GetAccessProfile: Failure responding to request:
     StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=400 
    Code="BadRequest" Message="Getting static credential is not allowed because this cluster 
    is set to disable local accounts."
```

This is my terraform code:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=2.96.0"
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "aks-rg" {
  name     = "aks-rg"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks-1" {
  name                = "aks-1"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.aks-rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.aks-rg.name
  dns_prefix          = "aks1"
  local_account_disabled = "true"

  default_node_pool {
    name       = "nodepool1"
    node_count = 3
    vm_size    = "Standard_D2_v2"
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  tags = {
    Environment = "Test"
  }
}
```

Is this a Terraform bug? Can I avoid the error?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it shouldn't matter, but I guess the `local_account_disabled` should be `bool`, so remove the quotation marks around `"true"` and check if that will work.

Comment: It is quite annoying, because the error occurs with every terraform apply. It is also not possible to update/delete the AKS with terraform. I have to do it manually. You are right it is a boolean but it does not matter for the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you [disable local accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/managed-aad#disable-local-accounts) you need to activate AKS-managed Azure Active Directory integration as you have no more local accounts to authenticate against AKS.

This example enables RBAC, Azure AAD & Azure RBAC:

```
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks-1" {
  ... 

  role_based_access_control {
    enabled = true

    azure_active_directory {
      managed                = true
      tenant_id              = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
      admin_group_object_ids =  ["OBJECT_IDS_OF_ADMIN_GROUPS"]
      azure_rbac_enabled     = true
    }
  }
}
```

If you dont want AAD integration you need set `local_account_disabled = "false"`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand my mistake now. It works now. Maybe this should be underlined in the Terraform documentation.

Comment: i added this to the terraform docs: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/kubernetes_cluster#local_account_disabled

Comment: I cannot tell you how many different pages I visited on Azure k8s RBAC and Terraform's modules. Such confusion. You have made my day :)